# Como concatenar valor a uma coluna de uma tabela em csv?

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

Estou a ter dificuldades em criar um algoritmo que adicione um elemento na terceira fila no ficheiro CSV na linguagem  Python.

O ficheiro tem seguintes dados:

```
   Serial;             Imei;           Número;       Icc;         Stock
869606020314526;   869606020314526;  934097609;  20000736862016;  Stock
```

A ideia é inserir o número +244 em cada inicio do número, ficando: +244934097609

Comment: Pode compartilhar o que já tentou, o código e o erro específico em que esbarrou?

Comment: Se uma das respostas abaixo resolveu o seu problema e não restou nenhuma dúvida, escolha a que você mais gostou e marque-a como correta/aceita ao clicar no "✅" que está ao lado dela, o que também marca a sua pergunta como resolvida. Se ainda te resta alguma dúvida ou gostaria de maiores esclarecimentos, fique à vontade para comentar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solução usando pandas:

```py
import pandas as pd 

df=pd.read_csv("file.csv", sep=";")
df.columns=[k.strip() for k in df.columns]
df['Número']=['+244'+str(k) for k in df["Número"]]

print(df)
```

Retorna:

```
            Serial             Imei         Número             Icc    Stock
0  869606020314526  869606020314526  +244934097609  20000736862016    Stock
```

Salvando:

```py
df.to_csv("file.csv", index=False)
```

Comment: Boa solução! +1

Comment: Nunca usei pandas, mais vou testar o seu exemplo

Answer (score 1):

Oi, tem dois jeito de se fazer isso, o mais elegante e utilizando uma biblioteca para o python chamado "pandas" esse é o [link](https://pandas.pydata.org) para o site deles, tem como instalar usando o "pip" do python e tem toda documentação no site deles.

Porém vou escrever aqui uma forma menos elegante, mas resolve o seu problema.

Entrada : data.csv

```
Serial; Imei; Número; Icc; Stock 
869606020314526; 869606020314526; 934097609; 20000736862016; Stock
```

Script : numeroUpdate.py

```
file_in = open('data.csv','r')
file_out = open('numero_atualizado.csv','w+')

next(file_in) # Pois queremos pular a primeira linha.
file_out.write('Serial; Imei; Número; Icc; Stock\n') # Cabeçario do arquivo, e o "\n" é para pular de linha.

string = '' # Criado para podermos chamar o metodo join.

for line in file_in:
    line = line.split('; ') # No split, cortamos string. 
    numero = "+244" + line[2]
    line[2] = numero
    file_out.write(string.join(line))

file_out.close()
```

Acho que pode ajudar, qualquer coisa, só comentar.

Comment: Ao executar apresenta o seguinte erro: 


line 11, in <module>
    line[2] = numero
TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment
>>> 

strings são imutáveis em Python‍♂️